# What is the equinumerosity?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

1. What is the ***equinumerosity*** of the set which contains all the  ***finite sequences***  of ***natural numbers*** and why?
2. What is the ***equinumerosity*** of the set which contains all the  ***infinite sequences*** of ***real numbers*** and why?

About question ***1*** I use the statement "An infinite set and the set of its finite subsets are equinumerous". This means that the wanted set has the same equinumerosity as the natural numbers.
Please prove me if I'm wrong.

About question ***2*** I'm a bit lost. With some arguments, I come to the result that the set is finite or infinite but countable at best, but with other arguments come to the conclusion that the set is infinite and uncountable and I'm not sure about either.

Comment: [equinumerosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinumerosity) means "to have the same number of elements". Thus, it sounds strange to me "the equinumerosity of a set"

Comment: Having said that, 1) YES, the set of all finite sequences of natural numbers is [countably infinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set)

Comment: And 2) is [uncountable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set): we can define an infinite "identical" sequence $\{ r_i \}$ for each real $r$. Thus, we have at least as many sequences as reals.

Comment: You mean "[cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality)", not "[equinumerosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinumerosity)".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Uncountable is clear, but can we also show that the cardinality is not larger than that of the reals ?

Comment: @Peter Find an injection from sequences of reals to sequences of reals in $(0,1)$. Write the binary digits of each one (when there are two possible representation, pick one, say the representation with inifitely many 1s). Then build a new real by reading the binary digits of the real numbers in the sequence in diagonal. Prove you get an injection. It's enough to prove the "is not larger". The converse injection from reals to sequences of reals is trivial (use constant sequences). Then Cantor-Bernstein theorem, and you have a proof that they have the same cardinality.